# PropertyChanged doesnt get executed

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to implement MVP in windows forms, i have all controls binded to a corresponding property of a binding source, and i want, when the user change something and lost focus from the control, the propertychanged event to get executed immediately.
For now it is only get executed if i type in presenter -> e.g. view.Username = "something"; but i dont want this.

```
public string Username
    {
        get { return txtUsername.Text; }
        set {
            var oldValue = txtUsername.Text;
            txtUsername.Text = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name", oldValue, value);
        }
    }




    public class PropertyChangedExtendedEventArgs : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public virtual object OldValue { get; private set; }
    public virtual object NewValue { get; private set; }

    public PropertyChangedExtendedEventArgs(string propertyName, object oldValue,
           object newValue)
           : base(propertyName)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}




public partial class MasterForm : Form, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MasterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedExtendedEventArgs(propertyName, oldvalue, newvalue));
    }

    private void MasterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking *When the user change something and lost focus from the control, the propertychanged event to get executed immediately*.

This code shows how to capture the `LostFocus` event of your UI control to fire the event you want.

```
public partial class MasterForm : Form , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MasterForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        // Subscribe to the event here
        textBoxUsername.LostFocus += onUsernameLostFocus;
    }

    // Handle the event here
    private void onUsernameLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    string _username = string.Empty;
    public string Username
    {
        get => _username;
        set
        {
            if (_username != value)
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```